# Automatically setting a column to created_at during model instance creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

I have the following model (`sort_timestamp` is a datetime):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  [snip attr_accessible]
  acts_as_nested_set
  after_create :set_sort_timestamp

  private
  def set_sort_timestamp
    self.sort_timestamp = self.created_at
  end
end
```

I'm using https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set . This code doesn't set `sort_timestamp`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing the point of what you're doing here, you're probably looking for `before_create` if you'd like it to save when the row is created. Otherwise you'll have to add `self.save` to the method, but that will cause extra database calls, so `before_create` might be the better option.

(Basically, the flow of what you were doing before was that the model would be created, saved to the database, and then the object would modify its attribute `sort_timestamp` to be `created_at`; this is after your database commit, and only performed in memory (so not persisted, unless you were persisting it in another way later in the code).

EDIT: Actually, this probably won't work because created_at probably won't be set before the record is created. A few options:

1) Add `self.save` to end of your method with `after_create`
2) Use `Time.now` if the times `sort_timestamp` and `created_at` don't have to be exactly the same.
or, 3) Try adding default value to migration: [How to use created_at value as default in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087494/how-to-use-created-at-value-as-default-in-rails)

Comment: Changing `after_` to `before_create` doesn't do anything.

Comment: On second thought, before_create probably results in created_at being nil (because it isn't created yet). You could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087494/how-to-use-created-at-value-as-default-in-rails or otherwise using Time.now() if that's appropriate for your cause.

Comment: Remember, though, Time.now() might be different from created_at - if that's important then you'll have to use a different solution. Good luck! :)

Comment: It's close enough for practical purposes.

Comment: Could be a different day altogether though